# [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I'm making fixtures and when I try to load them I have an error. The relationship between Award and Movie is unidirectional, so I load first Award because it hasn't any reference. The error says:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException] Warning: spl_object_hash()
expects parameter 1 to be object, array given in
/Users/benatespina/Development/filmboot.web/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM‌/MongoDB/UnitOfWork.php line 1706.
```

This is my Fixture class:

```
namespace MyProject\MovieBundle\DataFixtures\MongoDB;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

use MyProject\MovieBundle\Document\Award;

class Awards extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface {
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager) {
        $awards = array(
            array(
                "name"     => "Sitges",
                "year"     => "1992",
                "category" => "Best director"
        );

        foreach ($awards as $i => $award) {
            $document = new Award();
            $document->setName    ($award["name"]);
            $document->setYear    ($award["year"]);
            $document->setCategory($award["category"]);

            $manager->persist($document);
            $this->addReference("award-" . $i, $award);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getOrder() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using $i in $this->addReference("award-" .$i, $award); but you are not defining it anywhere.

Comment: This is a because you are using a foreach instead of a for loop, you either need to change your loop or you need to add an $i that you self update

Answer (score 2):

This exception has nothing to do with symfony2 or doctrine-fixtures - it's a generic PHP exception.

You are trying to use a variable `$i` that has never been defined in your `addReference()` call.

```
$this->addReference("award-" .$i, $award);
```

Comment: I've edited my code and now I have the following error: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
 Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given in /Users/b
 enatespina/Development/filmboot.web/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/Mon
 goDB/UnitOfWork.php line 1706

Comment: you shouldn't edit questions like that ... i have answered your question but now this answer is useless and can't serve anybody else anymore. Just open a new question next time please.